# Installing dependencies through elastic beanstalk config files versus eb ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having trouble installing a specific dependency in my elastic beanstalk environment via a .config file in the .ebextensions directory.

Are there any issues caused by instead installing it directly onto the instance via "eb ssh"? If my application was auto-scaled or if I wanted to change the instance type, will the dependency be missing from these new instance(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be issues when the application get's auto-scaled. An EC2 instance provisioned by Elastic Beanstalk has the following MOTD:

> This EC2 instance is managed by AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Changes made via SSH
>   WILL BE LOST if the instance is replaced by auto-scaling. For more information
>   on customizing your Elastic Beanstalk environment, see our documentation here:
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Use the custom container approach suggested if you're aiming to create a highly customized beanstalk environment.